# OTP/XOR Cracking two ciphertexts that have the same key

Tags: cryptography, xor, one-time-password, cracking

How can I crack two ciphertexts that have used the same key twice? For example, `plaintext1` uses the key `"abcdefg"`, and `plaintext2` uses the key `"abcdefg"`.

I know that `ciphertext2 ^ ciphertext1` is equal to `plaintext1 ^ plaintext2`. And the method to crack `plaintext1 ^ plaintext2` is the same method to crack a "book cipher" (also sometimes called a "running key cipher", although a running key cipher isn't the same as a book cipher, right?)

I know that I'm supposed to use a dictionary attack, but I'm not sure which dictionary/wordlist I should use, and the algorithm used in cracking this. Can anyone provide me with a link, or some code that shows how to crack it?

I'm new to cryptography, and I just wanted to do this for fun. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common attack is to "slide" a common (but not too short) word along and `XOR` it against successive positions in the combined stream. Where the word was used in one stream, the XOR will (usually) produce readable text for the other stream.

Comment: Rather than worrying about pseudocode, I'd advise working it through by hand at least a couple of times; even more than with many other things, cryptanalysis really requires doing some work by hand to honestly understand what you're doing before you can write useful code.

Comment: It's helpful in the selection of the crib word if you know *something* about the plaintext - who it was from or to, what the rough subject might be...

Comment: @caf: You're certainly right that it's helpful, but it's rarely necessary unless they've gone to a *lot* of trouble to avoid common words.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it sometime this weekend.